# Upload file with tags through OwnCloud or NextCloud API

Tags: api, owncloud, nextcloud

I have a database of files that are already tagged. Now, I would like to upload these files to an OwnCloud or NextCloud Server and pass on my already existing tags so that they show up as tags in the respective system. I wasnt able yet to find a way how I could do that in the documentation, does anyone have an idea how I could do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a database of files"?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550487/nextcloud-file-tagging-through-webdav-script/42558542#42558542

Comment: Thank you, @Julian, finally some closure to this issue I was not able to solve.

Comment: Did you already find another solution for the tagging problem? I have implemented a small python REST deamon that runs on the nextcloud server for tagging uploaded files. If you are interested I could polish the code a bit, and make it available.

Comment: That would be great - I did not pursue it further back then because I was not able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just made available the source code of the (remote) file tagging micro-service for Nextcloud on github (https://github.com/julianthome/taggy). The implementation consists of two parts: 1) the taggy client for uploading files to the Nextcloud server, and for invoking the taggy server; 2) the taggy server for adding specified tags to uploaded files.

I will polish the code further within the next days. I am also planning to add SSL support which is important because username and password are currently transmitted unencrypted to the taggy server. The server uses these credentials in order to check whether the user can be properly authenticated before tagging any files.

Please let me know if you have other ideas, suggestions or feedback ;)

Kind regards